# Two different coolants in my radiator

Tags: coolant, cadillac

What happens if I have two different kinds of antifreeze coolant in my Cadillac Catera?

Comment: What are the 2 coolants in your radiator?

Comment: Can you clarify, did you mean "kinds" (as in difference chemical makeup) or did you mean "brands" (Prestone vs Peak)?

Answer (score 3):

If the coolants are compatible, they will mix and there shouldn't be any problems. However, if the two coolants are not compatible with each other, you will likely get nasty deposits. If there's enough of them, it may cause an obstruction and your engine will overheat.